How to generate a token from the web client and display it with Razor views
I have implemented JWT in Swagger, a token is generated correctly and works fine.
Recap API: one interface and one class
public interface ITokenRepository
{
    Tokens Authenticate(Users users);
}

public class TokenRepository : ITokenRepository
{
    Dictionary<string, string> UsersRecords = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { "myuser","mypass"},
        { "user","password"}
    };
}

The controller:
public CourseService _courseservice;

private readonly ITokenRepository _tokenRepository;

public CourseController(CourseService courseservice,ITokenRepository tokenRepository)
{
    _courseservice = courseservice;
    _tokenRepository = tokenRepository;
}

[HttpPost]
[Route("GetToken")]
public IActionResult Authenticate(Users usersdata)
{
    var token = _tokenRepository.Authenticate(usersdata);

    if (token == null)
    {
        return Unauthorized();
    }

    return Ok(token);
}

I have an ASP.NET Core MVC web app with Razor view to display some basic endpoints, but I am struggling to generate the token from the web client.
If run from Swagger UI or Postman and pass user/password, it generates the token fine. I just need to learn how to generate the token from the web client.
Thank you

If run from Swagger UI or Postman and pass user/password, it generates the token fine -> which means your API worked well and it can generate an access token successfully. Then you might use httpclient in MVC application to call this API and pass the user/password and get the token back as well. What trapped you before?

Since we already had a correct API for generating the access token, we can send an http request to get that token and display it in cshtml files in the MVC application with codes below. We shall inject IHttpClientFactory into the Controller, and this also requires add builder.Services.AddHttpClient(); in Program.cs file. More details about sending http request can be seen in this document.
private readonly IHttpClientFactory _httpClientFactory;

public HomeController(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
{
    _httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;
}

public async Task<IActionResult> IndexAsync()
{
    var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "https://localhost:7035/home/generateJwt");
    var httpClient = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
    var httpResponseMessage = await httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage);
    if (httpResponseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var token = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
    ViewBag.accessToken = token;
    return View();
}

<div>
    <laber>jwt token is :</laber>
    <p>@ViewBag.accesstoken</p>
</div>


Many thanks for replying to my post.
I still need to get authenticated so the token gets generated.
How do I send the credentials?  Do I need to change HttpMethod.Get to HttpMethod.Post as well?

Finally, I learned how to do it.
First, I created a class (credentials) that contains parameters expected by the API in json format
Code below that worked for me.
public async Task<IActionResult> GetToken() 
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {


        //define the endpoint to call
        var endpoint = new Uri("https://localhost:7089/api/GetToken");


        //Create the message I want to send then initialize it
             
        var token = new credentials()
        {
            name = "user",
            password = "userpassword"
        };

        //convert the token object to serialized 
        var newpostjason = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(token);

        //specify the payload
        var payload = new StringContent(newpostjason, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        //ready to be sent and store in result variable

        var result = client.PostAsync(endpoint, payload).Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        return View(result);
    }

